# Single slit diffraction momentum of particle

Tags: optics, diffraction

I was studying single slit diffraction theory
from a book which said and i quote

**"we may assume the light source to be sufficiently far away from the slit that the photons approaching the slit can be assumed to have momentum in only the y direction"**

I don't understand how distance between the source and slit would change the momentum in x direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light spreads radially from the source to the slit. This means that the angular spread is greater for smaller radii. Here’s a diagram representing the same.

[image]

The farther you go, the light that passes through the slit are more or less parallel to each other.

Comment: oh i got it now

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you fix the size and location of the slit. Say the initial position of the photon is in line with the slit. If the photon is nearby the slit, there is a large range of angles the photon can make such that it can still make it through. However, if the photon is far away, there is only a small range. See the beautiful recreation below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks i understand now